# How to make colormap of this colorbar image attached?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

[image]

0

I want to make a colormap used in the attached image.

```
 img = imread('/path/Screenshot 2022-04-12 at 2.14.16 PM.png')
 colors_from_img = img[:, 0, :]
 my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_cmap', colors_from_img, N=651)
 y = random_sample((100, 100))
 imshow(y, cmap=my_cmap);plt.colorbar().png')
```

Looking forward to your inputs

Comment: I think this is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71448283/8881141

Comment: Colorbar image is different. Also the extraction column. Would be a great help if could help with this colorbar image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to transpose the strategy linked in my comment from vertical to horizontal. To avoid random guessing, you analyze first the image dimensions, then guesstimate what level the horizontal line should be (ca 66/3) and what the step for the color bars is (ca 616/11). Finally, you have to [normalize the image](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#extended-colorbar-with-continuous-colorscale) for the range -0.3 ... 0.5 and tell matplotlib that values above and below should also be considered (`extend="both"`). This leads us to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import numpy as np

img = plt.imread('test.png')
#analyze image dimensions
#print(img.shape)
#>>> (66, 616, 4)
colors_from_img = img[22, 60::56, :]

#generate color map
my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_cmap", colors_from_img, N=len(colors_from_img))
#normalize with boundaries
my_norm = BoundaryNorm(np.linspace(-0.3, 0.5, 9), my_cmap.N, extend="both")
y = 2*np.random.random_sample((20, 20))-1
plt.imshow(y, cmap=my_cmap, norm=my_norm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the color bar to be an image, I would suggest the tutorial in the formula for an [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html). I have set the color names similar to the colors in your image, but you can change them to whatever colors you like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 0.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
c = ['darkblue', 'lightblue', 'aquamarine', 'green', 'lime', 'yellow','orange','red']
cmap = (mpl.colors.ListedColormap(c)
        .with_extremes(over='purple', under='white'))

bounds = [-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    cax=ax,
    boundaries=[-10] + bounds + [10],
    extend='both',
    extendfrac='auto',
    ticks=bounds,
    spacing='uniform',
    orientation='horizontal',
    #label='Custom extension lengths, some other units',
)
fig.savefig('my_colorbar.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]